# Configure PHP 5.6 with Apache2 on Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, php, debian-jessie

I'm trying to install PHP 5.6 on Debian 8.

```
:~# php -v
PHP 5.6.40-10+0~20190807.18+debian8~1.gbp5642bf (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Unfortunetly, the web server show the contents of the PHP file ( in the web browser):

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

restart apache2 didn't fix it.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the **libapache2-mod-php package**?

Do you have under the directory /etc/apache2/mods-available two files like this ones:

- php5.6.conf
- php5.6.load

I have just installed PHP 5.6 on a Debian 10 (following [this guide](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/10/03/how-to-install-php-5-6-on-debian-buster-10-gnu-linux-easy-guide/3/) as it is an old version) with no problems, it just worked